# UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am trying to run code below.Everything is going well until I have tried to fit training data and label.

I keep taking below error. I could not find why. Could you please help me?

> UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported     [[node
>   metrics/accuracy/Cast (defined at :1)
>   ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_53201]
>
> Function call stack: distributed_function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, GRU, Embedding, CuDNNGRU, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import tensorflow as tf

datas=pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='delimiter', engine='python')
targets=pd.read_csv('label.csv', sep='delimiter', engine='python')

data=datas['XDESCRIPTION'].values.tolist()
target=targets['YMode'].values.tolist()

cutoff=int(len(data)*0.80)
x_train,x_test=data[:cutoff],data[cutoff:]
y_train,y_test=target[:cutoff],target[cutoff:]


tokenizer=Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(target)

x_train_tokens=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
num_tokens=[len(tokens) for tokens in x_train_tokens +x_test_tokens]
num_tokens=np.array(num_tokens)
np.mean(num_tokens)

max_tokens=np.mean(num_tokens)+2*np.std(num_tokens)
max_tokens=int(max_tokens)
max_tokens

np.sum(num_tokens<max_tokens)/len(num_tokens)

x_train_pad=pad_sequences(x_train_tokens, maxlen=max_tokens)
x_test_pad=pad_sequences(x_test_tokens, maxlen=max_tokens)

idx=tokenizer.word_index
inverse_map=dict(zip(idx.values(),idx.keys()))

def tokens_to_string(tokens):
    words=[inverse_map[token] for token in tokens if token!=0]
    text=" ".join(words)
    return text

model=Sequential()
embedding_size=41
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_words,output_dim=embedding_size,input_length=max_tokens))
model.add(GRU(units=16,return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(units=8,return_sequences=True))
model.add(GRU(units=4))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=np.array(x_train_pad), y=np.array(y_train),epochs=2,batch_size=256)
```

Comment: Are you doing any string to float casting?

Comment: Probably your y_train and y_test are strings, then you should convert it into numbers

Comment: Could you post a sample of `data.csv` and `label.csv`?

Answer (score 5):

Definitively your `y_train` and `y_test` arrays are string arrays. You can see that by these two lines

```
target=targets['YMode'].values.tolist()`

y_train,y_test=target[:cutoff],target[cutoff:]
```

If your data in the csv file is numeric, you can cast the target array to int like this

```
target = [int(lab) for lab in target]
```

However, if your data is categorical, you can solve that problem doing Label encoding to your data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

target=targets['YMode'].values.tolist()
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = np.array(label_encoder.fit_transform(target))
y_train,y_test=Y[:cutoff],Y[cutoff:]
```